# flash and usb drives showing up as RO in GNOME

Tags: usb, flash, read-only

Cannot drag and drop items onto flash and USB drive.  Receiving an error stating that the device is read-only, however, I am able to copy to these devices from the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Do a sudo format of the pendrive once you have saved a security copy of the content and then try it again, the best compatibility goes for FAT32 and not NTFS, hope you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds just like the issue I had.  See bug #1332623 related to Thunar.  I worked-around this by switching from thunar ("File Manager" in menu) to nautilus or pcmanfm.

There is no reason to have to do anything special concerning the FAT32 USB flash drive.